# Can I convert the output of a for-loop into a column in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I'm getting latitude and longitude for neighborhoods in Baltimore and have a working `for` loop that lists the neighborhood names with the latitude and longitude, but need to put the output into a dataframe.

```py
# Gets a list from excel spreadsheet
def readcolumn(filename,column):
    #select sheet name and selct column as index,index_col=0
    df = pd.read_excel(filename)
    headername = list(df)
    print(headername)
    column_data =df[list(df)[column]].tolist()
    return  column_data

# Converts the neighborhood column in the spreadsheet to a list
neigh_list = readcolumn('BaltimoreNeighborhoods.xlsx', 2)

# Outputs the neighborhood, lat, and long
for neigh in neigh_list:
    try:
        geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="bmore_explorer")
        location = geolocator.geocode(neigh)
        latitude = location.latitude
        longitude = location.longitude
        print(neigh, latitude, longitude)
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error, skipping address...', e)
```

The output looks like this:

```
Arlington, MD 39.3486919 -76.6826661
Ashburton, MD 39.3279621 -76.6710811
Callaway-Garrison, MD 39.3321612 -76.6794359
Central Park Heights, MD 39.3444594 -76.6712351
```

I want to convert this list into a df.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to build the matrix and then convert that to a pandas DataFrame.

```
df = []
for neigh in neigh_list:
    try:
        geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="bmore_explorer")
        location = geolocator.geocode(neigh)
        latitude = location.latitude
        longitude = location.longitude
        df.append([location, latitude, longitude])
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error, skipping address...', e)
df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['location', 'latitude', 'longitude'])
```

As an aside, pandas also has functionality to [read straight from an excel sheet](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) which may simplify your readcolumn function

Comment: How do you get the output of the for-loop into the dataframe?

Comment: This method uses the for loop to build a list and then at the end, converts it to a dataframe. An alternate method is to initialize df as an empty dataframe (i.e. df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['location', 'latitude', 'longitude']). Then for each neighborhood you would create a row and append it i.e. row = pd.DataFrame([[location, latitude, longitude]], columns=['location', 'latitude', 'longitude']) and then df = df.append(row, ignore_index=True)

Answer (score 0):

The append line fixed the problem. May not be the most logical way, but it worked.

```
# Prints out the neighborhood list with the latitude and longitude
df = []
for neigh in neigh_list:
    try:
        geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="bmore_explorer")
        location = geolocator.geocode(neigh)
        latitude = location.latitude
        longitude = location.longitude
        print(neigh, latitude, longitude)
        df.append({'location':location,
                  'latitude': latitude,
                  'longitude': longitude})
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error, skipping address...', e)

df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['Location', 'Latitude', ;Longitude'])
```

Comment: Check quote issue at the end. By the way, *columns* is redundant as `DataFrame` will use dictionary keys. Consider renaming *df* as *df_list* to avoid confusion with final named object. Also, you should acknowledge or accept previous answer that helped guide you to your final.